# taylor polynomial and upper bound error

Tags: functions

Find the degree 2 Taylor polynomials $P_2(x)$ at $x = a$ for the following functions. (a) $\sqrt{x}$ at $a = 4$ (b) $\cos x$ at $a = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

In addition, find an upper bound for the error committed when it’s used to estimate the functional value at $x = a + h, \quad (h > 0)$ in terms of $h$.

Since it said $x=a$, does it mean the $P_2(x)$ equal to $2$ only??

Comment: Well, $(-2)^2=4$ too... Are you okay with your definitions of "Taylor Polynomials" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think for the x power you sub c=4 (in the R2(x)) cuz it's monotone decreasing
For the cos x you don't sub anything just find the Max of sinC which is 1 and put it back to (R2(x))

The key is that ***Remember*** **conceptually** you are trying to find "upper bound"--as big as possible  so in that case it doesn't matter how much h itself varies.

so I think for
(a )   It's the 2 to the power of -5/96 *|h to the power of 3|

(b)  It's 1/6 * |h to the power of 3|

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It greatly helps readability to format answers using MathJax.

Comment: It is nice that you've identified an older Question that remained unanswered and tried to provide one.  However I'm unable to follow your reasoning here, and I suspect most future Readers would require your post to be clarified.